# Restarting an EC2 instance on the instance that is supposed to be restarted

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm running through a loop with a PHP script that's on AWS instance. From my experiences with AWS, as soon as the instance is stopped, all of the code that's in the process of being executed is stopped. What I have is this:

```
<?php
require("vendor/autoload.php");
use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;

$instance_id = 'instance_id';
$creds = array('key' => 'key', 
                'secret' => 'secret', 
                'region' => 'us-west-2');
$client = Ec2Client::factory($creds);
$instance = array('InstanceIds' => array($instance_id), 'DryRun' => false);

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    // Execute irrelevant code
    // .....

    $result = $client->stopInstances($instance);
    sleep(300);
    $result = $client->startInstances($instance);
}
?>
```

So, my question is this: Once the instance is stopped, everything that is written after that will not be executed since the instance will be stopped, right? The loop will not continue on to the next iteration, right? If so, then how could I get around that?

Comment: Don't run the script on the instance itself?

Comment: Yeah, that's an option. How could I get the instance to start back up again without have to manually run the script to start it again?

Comment: You could `exec` out to the AWS CLI. `aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids i-1a2b3c4d`

Comment: How could I reboot with PHP?

Comment: `exec('aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids i-1a2b3c4d');`